# How to call function in class PHP from JAVASCRIPT. CHAT

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, chat

i want to integrate process file for chat in class php.

If i leave the process.php file in same folder ( public_html ) with chat.js it's worked correctly. But when i put in my class XHR doesnt updated after time setted.

When i send the message, he stored in my chat.txt, but doesn't display. Some help please..

I have this:

```
private function handlePostData($page)
{   
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

            switch ($page)
            {

                case 'process':
                    $this->getUserFunctions()->chat_process();
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

This is the function from main file.

Next i have this: (this is the function in my class with process.php file)

```
public function chat_process(){
$function = $_POST['function'];

$log = array();

switch($function) {

     case('getState'):
         if(file_exists('chat.txt')){
           $lines = file('chat.txt');
         }
         $log['state'] = count($lines);
         if($state == $count){
             $log['state'] = $state;
             $log['text'] = false;

             }
             else{
                 $text= array();
                 $log['state'] = $state + count($lines) - $state;
                 foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line)
                   {
                       if($line_num >= $state){
                     $text[] =  $line = str_replace("\n", "", $line);
                       }

                    }
                 $log['text'] = $text; 
             }
         break; 

     case('update'):
        $state = $_POST['state'];
        if(file_exists('chat.txt')){
           $lines = file('chat.txt');
         }
         $count =  count($lines);
         if($state == $count){
             $log['state'] = $state;
             $log['text'] = false;

             }
             else{
                 $text= array();
                 $log['state'] = $state + count($lines) - $state;
                 foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line)
                   {
                       if($line_num >= $state){
                     $text[] =  $line = str_replace("\n", "", $line);
                       }

                    }
                 $log['text'] = $text; 
             }

         break;

     case('send'):
      $nickname = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['nickname']));
         $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
          $message = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['message']));
     if(($message) != "\n"){

         if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $message, $url)) {
            $message = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="'.$url[0].'" target="_blank">'.$url[0].'</a>', $message);
            } 


         fwrite(fopen('chat.txt', 'a'), "<span>". $nickname . "</span>" . $message = str_replace("\n", " ", $message) . "\n"); 

     }
         break;

}

echo json_encode($log);
}
```

And my chat.js is like this:

```
    function Chat () {
    this.update = updateChat;
    this.send = sendChat;
    this.getState = getStateOfChat;
}

//gets the state of the chat
function getStateOfChat(){
    if(!instanse){
         instanse = true;
         $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/?exec=process",
               data: {  
                        'function': 'getState',
                        'file': file
                        },
               dataType: "json",

               success: function(data){
                   state = data.state;
                   instanse = false;
               },
            });
    }    
}

//Updates the chat
function updateChat(){
     if(!instanse){
         instanse = true;
         $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/?exec=process",
               data: {  
                        'function': 'update',
                        'state': state,
                        'file': file
                        },
               dataType: "json",
               success: function(data){
                   if(data.text){
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.text.length; i++) {
                            $('#chat-area').append($("<p>"+ data.text[i] +"</p>"));
                        }                                 
                   }
                   document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollTop = document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollHeight;
                   instanse = false;
                   state = data.state;
               },
            });
     }
     else {
         setTimeout(updateChat, 1500);
     }
}

//send the message
function sendChat(message, nickname)
{       
    updateChat();
     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/?exec=process",
           data: {  
                    'function': 'send',
                    'message': message,
                    'nickname': nickname,
                    'file': file
                 },
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(data){
               updateChat();
           },
        });
}
```

Comment: AJAX is not a great solution for a real-time chat app. Websockets would be a preferable technology.

Comment: @ADyson ok but i can integrate the websockets in class php ? i go now to documentate about websockets.

Comment: yes there are php implementations of websockets available.

Comment: @ADyson you know how to run server file (php-socket.php) on cPanel? In my desktop is already done but when i upload file on web host, does not connect with websockets. I must run something or i need to do some settings?

Comment: Since you mention cPanel I assume you're using some shared hosting? I doubt you can do that in a shared host unfortunately, as you need to set the process running and ensure it doesn't stop, otherwise it cannot listen for connections or keep them open. You would need dedicated hosting, or a cloud environment which supports you starting long-running processes. If you can't move your hosting to anything more suitable, then yes maybe you would need to return to the AJAX idea, but it's a lot less efficient.

Comment: Alternatively, if you can find a cheap host which supports ASP.NET Core, and you're prepared to learn something new (assuming you haven't done it before) then writing a chat app with ASP.NET Core and SignalR (which is just basically an enhanced version of websockets) is really quite easy, and since .NET Core can run on Linux you might find it's not too expensive to host. Or you can host it relatively cheaply on Azure (using Azure SignalR too). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio has a chat tutorial

Comment: @ADyson yeah i use some shared hosting, thank you so much for answers.I understand.